# Node.js REST API eror

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have problems with the REST API.

I have a file named route. In which I make a request that is then passed to the server where it is called. In my third request, I want to select an ID to pass it as an API and write to call the page inside/:id, but I only get an error  (This is a POST request)

```
    const post_inside = (req, res) => {
    var config = {
        user:'postgres',
        database:'my',
        password: '1',
        host:'localhost',
        port:5432,
        max:10,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
    var pool = new pg.Pool(config)

    pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
        if(err){
            return console.error('error')
        }
client.query("SELECT *,to_char(data_roz::date , 'YYYY-MM-DD') as data_roz from sch.idv_p where phone=$1",[req.body.login], function(err, result){
done()
return_data.pupil2 =result
if (err) {
res.end()
return console.error("error")
}
client.query('select * from table1 ($1,$2)',[req.body.login,req.body.date], function(err, result){
return_data.discipline =result 
if (err){
res.end()
return console.error("error")
} 


//3 HERE
client.query("select id from table3 where phone=$1",[req.body.login], function(err, result){
    return_data.id =result 
    if (err){
    res.end()
    return console.error("error")
    }

 res.render('inside/:id',{pupil2:return_data.pupil2,discipline:return_data.discipline,id:return_data.id})
    })})}}


module.exports = {
    post_inside
}
```

server:

```
app.post('/inside/:id',urlencodedParser,db.post_inside)
```

I want to call the same file, but for example as inside/2555

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Widada Error: Cannot POST /inside